# Unable to compile on QT for Android

Tags: android, c++, qt

I am new to QT programming and am trying to build a simple program on Android. I have installed QT 5.8, latest Android SDK, NDK and apache ant, but it gives the same error. I searched about this issue and tried using older versions of QT(5.5.1 and 5.7.0) , Android SDK as well as NDK, but its not helping. I tried giving the build path a shorter name, removed all the folders which had spaces in the title and reinstalled everything. Please help.

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtI7U.jpg)

```
11:40:56: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
11:40:56: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\android_armv7\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" --input C:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/Examples/Qt-5.7/quick/demos/build-calqlatr-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_7_0-Debug/android-libcalqlatr.so-deployment-settings.json --output C:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/Examples/Qt-5.7/quick/demos/build-calqlatr-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_7_0-Debug/android-build --deployment bundled --android-platform android-25 --jdk "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131" --ant E:/Android/apache-ant-1.9.6/bin/ant.bat
Generating Android Package
  Input file: C:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/Examples/Qt-5.7/quick/demos/build-calqlatr-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_7_0-Debug/android-libcalqlatr.so-deployment-settings.json
  Output directory: C:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/Examples/Qt-5.7/quick/demos/build-calqlatr-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_7_0-Debug/android-build/
  Application binary: C:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/Examples/Qt-5.7/quick/demos/build-calqlatr-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_7_0-Debug/libcalqlatr.so
  Android build platform: android-25
  Install to device: No
Application binary is not in output directory: C:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/Examples/Qt-5.7/quick/demos/build-calqlatr-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_7_0-Debug/android-build//libs/armeabi-v7a/libcalqlatr.so. Please run 'mingw32-make install INSTALL_ROOT=C:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/Examples/Qt-5.7/quick/demos/build-calqlatr-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_7_0-Debug/android-build/' first.
11:41:09: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\android_armv7\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" exited with code 7.
Error while building/deploying project calqlatr (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.7.0))
When executing step "Build Android APK"
11:41:09: Elapsed time: 01:15.
```

Comment: Based on the screenshot, it seems the `install` command invokes a Linux command `cp -f ...`, but you are on Windows hence the error. You should indicate how you build your program.

Answer (score 0):

Check for build.xml in your output path

```
C:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/Examples/Qt-5.7/quick/demos/build-calqlatr-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_7_0-Debug/android-build/
```

and also check

```
TEMPLATE = app
```

in your pro file if this is not there append this.